# Would I need to refer to self with weak in AFNetworkingReachability block

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, afnetworking

As the title says: Do I need to make a weak reference to self, when calling functions in a AFNetworkingReachability block like so?

```
__weak myViewController* weakSelf = self;

     [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status)
        {

            switch (status) {
            case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:

                DLog(@"No Internet Connection");

                NSLog([weakSelf reachable] ? @"YES" : @"NO");

               weakSelf.aProperty = aPropertyValue. 

               [weakSelf loadPlaces]; // This function does also contain a block

             break;
            default:

                break;
            }
        }];
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your view controller doesn't have a strong reference (either directly or indirectly) to `AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager`, then no.  You only need to follow this pattern to break strong reference cycles.

Watch our for indirect strong reference cycles, which clang won't warn you about. For example, your view controller could have a `strong` property to an API object, which could have a reference to AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, which could strongly reference the reachability manager.

If you're following the correct rules for properties - only using `strong` to indicate ownership, and `weak` otherwise - you will usually be okay.